# How do I find similarity between addresses with Mahout?

Tags: mahout

Need help and advise. Have setup a 5 hadoop with mahout cluster

I have 2 sets of data:

- table 1: id1, address1
- table 2: id2, address2
- how do I go about finding a similarity scoring with mahout so it'll compare addresses in both files so that I'd get the following result?

result: address1, address2, score

Have done:

1. Merged files to one csv
2. convert to sequence file: seqdirectory,
3. vectorise: seq2sparse (-wt tfidf )

Not entirely sure where to go after this. recommendation or clustering. how to use jaccard index etc. need pointers and examples.

Answer (score 1):

While you can apply a generic text similarity algorithm to addresses, I am pretty certain it will give poor results, because any generic algorithm will not account for misspellings. "Main St" will be as similar to "Main Dr" as "Main Street". "Apt 203" and "#203" aren't related.

That is -- I don't think a vectorized representation is the basis for a good fuzzy matching algorithm here. And so Mahout won't be useful, directly, though might provide some infrastructure to build your own clustering of non-vector data on.

I'd back up and define your algorithm before choosing tools.

Comment: thank u for your response sean.

another scenario/question:

if i have the following, can i do classification and predict the postcode for a given addresses?

file 1 (to train a model): id, full text address, postcode 
file 2 (to test): id, full text addr

will it be possible to do this with mahout?

thank u

Comment: I'd stop thinking about Mahout, which is a tool, and decide first what process you need a tool for. Think about how a classifier works... what property of the street's name tells you where it is? while two addresses on Main St *in the same city* probably have the same post code, any two given streets could be adjacent or miles apart. Classifiers aren't appropriate. Instead, you probably want to find nearest fuzzy matches and find a majority vote for the post code among addresses you already know.

Comment: What is the use case of trying to predict the postcode? Would it make much more sense to use a maps geocoding API where you can give it an address and find the post code?

Example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

Using Mahout for address similarity may be too much. Have you considered using a lot simpler algorithm like SimHash? Following is a great tutorial about it. Java library for SimHash and for finding Shingles etc is available on Google code.

http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/

You will find lib here

http://code.google.com/p/simhash/